# Cannot write to usb after formatting to ext4

Tags: permissions, partition, usb, ext4, steam

I am running galliumOs on a chromebook and wanted to put steam games on a separate usb drive so I bought a 128Gb USB and tried formatting to ext4 using GParted as well as the command `sudo mkfs.ext4 -L "plz work" /dev/sda1`. However now I cannot write to the drive to create new files and Steam will not create a library folder there:

```
Couldn't write /media/douglas/plz work/.steam_exec_test.sh: Permission denied
```

Steam says that its permission was denied to access the filesystem and when I try to use the steam library settings to create a new folder there it fails and says that it can't write to the drive because it is read only. I have checked the drive settings and they're grayed out but claim the drive has read write permissions. When I go onto my Windows laptop and reformat the drive as NTFS it I can write to it again but once I format it as ext4 I can no longer write to it at all. I am still fairly new to Linux terminals and commands so if you could walk me through what I need to do as best as you can so I can do it but also learn how to use it in the future it would be HUGELY appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `sudo chown -R your_username "/media/douglas/plz work"`. Maybe consider using a label without a space in the middle.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yup I realized my mistake with the name as soon as I tried a similar command to this and it complained about it. However, you are a godsend because that worked flawlessly so far! Thank you so much. So did that just change its permissions from root?

Comment: Artem you should change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The root folder of any formatted POSIX compatible filesystem is owned by root by default and only root can create files/directories in it.

You can fix this issue by changing permissions this way:

```
sudo chown -R your_username "/media/douglas/plz work"
```

You could consider using a label without a space in the middle because the space is often inconvenient to use in the terminal and scripts.

If you intend to use your device with other operating systems, including Windows, I strongly suggest using exFAT or NTFS instead (the latter now has a native Linux driver and works fast).